# data type mismatch in criteria expression(VB)

Tags: sql, vb.net, database-connection

I seem to keep on getting the 'data type mismatch in criteria expression' error whenever i try to read in information from an access database, the data from within the database is being added to a listview.. Here is the following code:

```
 POStable.Clear()

    connection1.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Shop.mdb"
    connection1.Open()
    POSAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from items where barcode = '" & txtBarcode.Text & "'", connection1)
    CommandBuilder = New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(POSAdapter)
    POSAdapter.Fill(POStable)             ' ****
    connection1.Close() 


    If POStable.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Item does not exist")
    Else
        Dim objListItem As ListViewItem
        objListItem = ListViewPOS.Items.Add(POStable.Rows(0)(1).ToString)
        objListItem.SubItems.Add(1)
        objListItem.SubItems.Add("£" & (POStable.Rows(0)(2).ToString))
    End If
```

The part above in BOLD is where i get the error. Ive connected to a database which contains one table called items. In that table there is just one row and 4 columns used for testing: barcode, item, price and quantity.

I was hoping if someone could help me explain why i have the error?
Thanks

Comment: if `txtBarcode.Text` is blank or contains illegal characters that error could result, or if barcode column is not text

Comment: In the database ive set the testing barcode to be 123. Even when i enter that into the textbox i still get the data type mismatch error. Ah never mind. I see that the data type for the barcode itself was number. Have changed it to text and it is now working. Thank you!

Comment: but what is the database column TYPE?

Comment: It was number.. but have since changed it to text. Silly mistake on my part. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try This if your textbox contains illigal characters

```
POSAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from items where barcode = [" & txtBarcode.Text & "]", connection1)
```